# am start -n format, why the forward slash?

Tags: android, adb

I've always been able to start my application from the shell via something like this:

adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.rutski89.Green/.GreenMainActivity

However, I never really questioned where the -n flag's parameter gets its format, and now I'm getting curious. I mean, the actual activity class is "com.rutski89.Green.GreenMainActivity", so why do I have to shove that forward slash in there in between the package name and the class name? (I'm talking about the "com.rutski89.Green/.GreenMainActivity")

Is there a document on this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

com.rutski89.Green/.GreenMainActivity

is shorthand for:
com.rutski89.Green/com.rutski89.Green.GreenMainActivity

which is a component name, made up of your apps package name,
followed by the class to target.